# Matching a string value with a list of regex present in a file of regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match a value with all the regular expressions present in a file of regex expressions. I wrote the following code to match a string `VALUE` with all the strings present in a file.

```
if File.open("/Users/jshaw/mapping/addID.txt").lines.any?{|line| line.include?(VALUE)}

    var badID = "true"

end'
```

However, I need to match a VALUE with the regex present in a file of regular expressions. Could anyone help me in this?

I have tried this but I need to put all regex in one file as I have more than 200 regex.

```
String IS_BAD_ID = "false"
String ClientID = "10.22.shaw"
if File.open("/Users/jshaw/mapping/addID.txt").lines.any?{ |line| Regexp.new(line) === ClientID}
          IS_BAD_ID = "true"        
end
```

I am always getting IS_BAD_ID value as false.

Comment: What have you tried? Surely you looked at some Ruby tutorials for using regex.

Comment: @4castle
Please see the edited post

Answer (score 0):

Compile the string into a regular expression object with `Regexp.new`.
Compare your regular expressions and target string with `===`.
Strip the newline character that `.lines` introduces with `.chomp`.

Which should leave you with:

```
String IS_BAD_ID = "false"
String ClientID = "10.22.shaw"
if File.open("/Users/jshaw/mapping/addID.txt").lines.any?{ |line| Regexp.new(line.chomp) === ClientID}
          IS_BAD_ID = "true"        
end
```

Comment: will .match() return a boolean value?

Comment: It returns a Match object that is evaluated as 'Truthy'. If there is no match, .match() returns nil, which is 'Falsy'.

Comment: I updated my answer to use `===` which does return a boolean value; this should be more correct.

Comment: I tried but the control does not enter the if block.
Please see my updated post.

Comment: `.lines` is also reading in the line break character which will make your regex test fail ("a\n" =\= "a"). I added a `chomp` to strip the trailing newline character.